# merging footer rows is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 13 columns. I want to display Grand Total budget in the footer row. I wanted to merge the cells together so that the footer row
 display properly. Below is my code

```
grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 7
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(1)
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(2)
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(3)
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(4)
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(5)
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(6)
```

although there are 13 columns, but if I remove the 7th column the I get an index out of range exception
I want to display this in the footer row

```
grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells(0).Text = " GRAND TOTAL BUDGET :" + GrandTotBudget.ToString()
```

My gridview looks like this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdBasicBudget" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true"
        Width="1500px" Style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ffffcc">
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Part" DataField="part" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Revisi" DataField="revisit" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Revision Date(m/d/y)" DataField="revision_date" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Year" DataField="year" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TYPE" DataField="type" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Task1" DataField="task" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Task2" DataField="task2" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Activity" DataField="activity" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contractor" DataField="contract" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tie" DataField="tie" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Planned_Amount($)" DataField="planned_amount" />

            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Estimated Delivery Date" DataField="estimated_del_date" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Notes" DataField="notes" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I want to display the calculated amount right underneath the planned amount cell and the Grand Total Budget behind the amount so I want something like this:

```
grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells(0).Text = " GRAND TOTAL BUDGET" + GrandTotBudget.ToString()
```

the GrandTotBudget part should always display underneath the planned amount cell.

I also tried writing the code this way:

```
Protected Sub grdBasicBudget_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdBasicBudget.RowDataBound
    Dim counter As Integer

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        For counter = 1 To grdBasicBudget.Columns.Count - 1
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(counter)
        Next

        e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = grdBasicBudget.Columns.Count - 1
        e.Row.Cells(0).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "This is a test"

    End If
End Sub
```

still the counter stops at 7th column. I know that my gridview has more than 7 columns. I am not sure why I am getting an error at 7th column saying
 argument out of range Exception was unhandled by user code.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
For i As Integer = grdBasicBudget.Columns.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    grdBasicBudget.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```